# SQLite INSERT and DELETE query is giving error, but not SELECt query

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm using SQLite(WebSQL) for saving form data locally in my Cordova mobile app.
The code below works well with `SELECT` query for the same table, but not with INSERT or DELETE queries.

It outputs error as: `could not prepare statement`

```
const usersDB = {
    add: function (firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country) {
        databaseHandler.db.readTransaction(
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    [firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country],
                    function (tx, results) {
                        console.log('User has been saved');
                    },
                    function (tx, error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: Failed to add user', error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    },
    selectAll: function (listUsers) {
        databaseHandler.db.readTransaction(
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY firstname",
                    [],
                    function (tx, results) {
                        listUsers(results);
                    },
                    function (tx, error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: Failed to list users', error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I searched dozens of discussion forms, but couldn't find a post with a solution about this.
Your help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A read transaction is used for reading only. A write transaction allows both reading and writing. A read transaction is started by a SELECT statement, and a write transaction is started by statements like CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INSERT, or UPDATE (collectively "write statements").

The `.readTransaction()` is used for read only queries and `.transaction()` is used for write queries.
So in my case I should use them in such way:

```
const usersDB = {
    add: function (firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country) {
        databaseHandler.db.transaction( // Write mode
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    [firstname, lastname, dob, email, phone, city, state, country],
                    function (tx, results) {
                        console.log('User has been saved');
                    },
                    function (tx, error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: Failed to add user', error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    },
    selectAll: function (listUsers) {
        databaseHandler.db.readTransaction( // read-only mode
            function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY firstname",
                    [],
                    function (tx, results) {
                        listUsers(results);
                    },
                    function (tx, error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: Failed to list users', error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```